# display item counts per month using JSON jquery each() IF statement (for loop?)

Tags: jquery, json, if-statement, for-loop, each

I have a JSON object of data containing items and their sales listed by month. I'd like to list the item sales/month inside a DIV alongside other info about each item.

Here's my JSON object:

```
var my_object= [{"item_id":"11","month":"February","sales":"7"}, {"item_id":"4","month":"February","sales":"2"},{"item_id":"11","month":"March","sales":"1"},{"item_id":"4","month":"March","sales":"2"}]
```

here's how i'd like the final HTML to look:

```
<ul><li><button value="4">item_id_4</button><div>where the item_4 sales/month (i.e., 2,2) should go</div></li>
<li><button value="11">item_id_11</button><div>where the item_11 sales/month (i.e, 7,1) should go</div></li></ul>
```

lastly, here's my not yet correct jquery/javascript attempt to display the item counts/month.

```
$(function(){   
$('button').each(function(){

var my_object = [{"item_id":"11","month":"February","sales":"7"},  {"item_id":"4","month":"February","sales":"2"},{"item_id":"11","month":"March","sales":"1"},{"item_id":"4","month":"March","sales":"2"}];

var button_value=$(this).val();

 $.each(my_object, function(i,item){

  if(item.item_id==button_value){       
    $('div').append(item.sales);
        } 

    });
}); 
});
```

As it stands, this script displays the sales for both items in EACH div, i.e., 2,2,7,1 instead of just displaying 2,2 and 7,1 in their respective item_id_4 and item_id_11 divs separately. This makes it seem like the if statement is doing at least something right in that the "my_object" item sales are listed in the order of the button value and not as they are ordered in the "my_object".

I'm not sure whether the issue is with the each() functions, the IF statement, or maybe something else not mentioned here. Any help fixing this script would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script seems to work fine except for the append line, where you tell jQuery to select all divs on the page and append your sales figures to them. Obviously that's not quite what you wanted. :)

Using your current HTML structure, changing that line to select the next div seems to work. (I've also saved the current button in $this.)

```
$this.next("div").append(item.sales);
```

Code here http://jsfiddle.net/meloncholy/ZhrZU/

Comment: Hi meloncholy, thanks so much for your answer, one follow up question if possible: instead of <div>"2""2"</div> i'd like it to be <div>2,2</div>. Can you advise on how to eliminate the quotations and adding commas in between each item.sales (noting that i don't want a comma after the last item.sales)? thanks! -tim

Comment: I don't see the quotes in the browsers I've just tried. If you do have problems, you could try `parseInt()`. To remove the last comma you could add another each iterator over the divs, something like this http://jsfiddle.net/meloncholy/ZhrZU/1/ Obviously it would make sense to make that code a little faster by caching `$(this)` and probably `$(this).html()`.

Comment: Hi meloncholy, yeah its weird, the quotations appear in chrome's but not firebug's developer tools. Other things: i noticed the item.sales don't become part of the source code, is that because those values are being rendered client side? Also, can you explain a little more about what you mean about caching $(this) and $(this).html? thanks, i promise that's all the questions! best wishes, tim

Comment: Ah, OK, that makes sense. Chrome does sometimes put quotes (and extra spacing) in the Dev Tools, but they're not really there - if you can't see it on the page, you're good basically. :) I presume it's to help people see when their server is sending strings with long chunks of whitespace on the front. Re. caching: all I meant was store $(this) in a variable inside the each to stop you calling jQuery for it three times, and similarly for $(this).html().

Comment: ok, thanks for the the tip on caching! your comments were really helpful, best wishes, -tim

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$(function(){   

    var my_object = [{"item_id":"11","month":"February","sales":"7"},  {"item_id":"4","month":"February","sales":"2"},{"item_id":"11","month":"March","sales":"1"},{"item_id":"4","month":"March","sales":"2"}];

    for (var i in my_object) {
        var cur = my_object[i];
        $('button[value=' + cur.item_id + ']').each(function() {
            var msg = 'Sales Month: ' + cur.month + ' Number: ' + cur.sales;
            $(this).parent().append('<div>' + msg + '</div>');
        });
    }
});
```

I wasn't quite sure what you wanted the staring HTML to be but I assumed the following

```
<ul><li><button value="4"></button></li>
<li><button value="11"></button></li></ul>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HdgmN/

Comment: Thanks Jared, if possible, might I trouble you for one follow up question: how might I modify your script such that the cur.sales for each item both end up in the same DIV? thanks again! -tim